# Start-up script in Azure app service to copy files from keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

We have a docker container that requires two files on the host to run. These two files are made available to the container by volume.

Now we want to host the container in Azure app service. My question is, how do I run some kind of start-up script that runs at deployment time, and will

1. download the two required files from keyvault
2. run some custom bash command
3. copy the files to a specific location on the host so the Container can access